# Openpyxl update values between sheets

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5, openpyxl

I have a workbook with a table and a main sheet. I want to change some values in that table and update the values in the main sheet.
The code I have tried is:

```
for row in ws1.iter_rows(row_offset=1,min_col=1,max_col=1):
    for cell in row:
        ws1.cell(row=cell.row, column=23).value = '=MyTable[@Price]'
```

The code runs fine but, creates a #REF error for all cells in that column in my main sheet.

I am unsure how to change the values on my table and have it update values on another sheet.

Comment: You are assigne a ` formula` to ` ws1.cell` , is this what you want? Which `worksheet` have the name `MyTable`? What is `@Price`? Edit your Question to explain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by pausing the script, making my changes, saving and closing the file, and resuming the script.

```
nwb.save("C:/mytable.xlsx")            
os.startfile("C:/mytable.xlsx")
print("After making changes and saving file, press enter to continue.")
input()

nwb = openpyxl.load_workbook("mytable.xlsx")
ws4 = nwb.get_sheet_by_name("mysheet")

for row in ws1.iter_rows(row_offset=1,min_col=1,max_col=1):
    for cell in row:          
        a = ws4.cell(row=cell.row, column=9).value 
        ws1.cell(row=cell.row, column=23).value = a
```

This may seem like a noob way to solve this, but I am very new to Python and programming in general.